# Find interpretations of formulas

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Consider the structure $A=<\mathbb{N},<;\cdot,1>$. Find the following interpretations of formulas (for an arbitrary valuation
v):

(c) $[\![ \forall x_1\exists x_1 P(x_1,x_2) ]\!]$

(d) $[\![ \exists x_3\forall x_4 P(x_1,x_2) ]\!]$

---

**Solution:**

(c) $$[\![ \forall x_1\exists x_1 P(x_1,x_2) ]\!]$$
$$=\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if for all } a\in |A|\text{ there is some } b\in |A|\text{ } [\![ P(x_1,x_2) ]\!]^{[x_1\to a][x_1\to b]}\\
0 \text{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$
$$[\![ P(x_1,x_2) ]\!]^{[x_1\to a][x_1\to b]}$$
$$=P^A([\![ x_1 ]\!]^{[x_1\to a][x_1\to b]},[\![ x_2 ]\!]^{[x_1\to a][x_1\to b]})$$
$$=P^A(b,v(x_2))$$
$$=b<v(x_2).$$

When I have arrived at this step I don't really know if I should say it's true or false. in (a) and (b) it was obvious since I had $\forall x_1\exists x_2(...)$ but i haven't said anything about the existence of $x_2$ in this particular case, what is $v(x_2)$ in this case (which feels kinda weird to me)? Is it just an arbitrary valuation of the natural numbers, that is, that I can just say this is true? Same goes for (d) then I get $v(x_1)<v(x_2)$ is this also true?  It was easier in (a) since I had "for all $a\in |A|$ there is some $b\in |A|$ such that $a<b$. If I haven't said that there exists an $x_2$ with this property nor have I said for all $x_2$ how can I then draw a conclusion?

Comment: Are you sure about the use of indices in (d)?

Comment: Things are messed up. Your formula (c) rebinds the same variable twice, $\forall x_1 \exists x_1 \dots$. You must mean $\exists x_2$.  Your formula (d) binds $x_3, x_4$ but these don't occur in the formula, which features $x_1, x_2$ as free variables... I assume you mean 1, 2 not 3, 4.

Comment: I have checked the exericse again, it says exactly the same as how i mentioned it.

Comment: You're having problems with the (c) solution ("why haven't I used $x_2$"?) because of the repeated bound variable, the 2nd $x_1$ should be $x_2$. You've wound up with a valuation that assigns two different values $a, b$ to $x_1$ – not a good sign.

Comment: Really? It says $\forall x_1 \exists x_1 P(x_1, x_2)$ ? Then it's (obviously) a typo, since what could that possibly mean. While you're checking & rechecking (c), you should do the same for (d). If that's really what it says, email your professor or TA or whomever.

Comment: I have no idea :/ I have already solved (a) which was $ \forall x_1\exists x_2(-||-)$ and (b) which was $\exists x_1\forall x_2(-||-)$...

Comment: Those (presumably) don't exhibit these problems.

Comment: I just replied to "the second $x_1$ should be $x_2$" which I have already solved, so I don't think he mean that :) But should probably email my professor since both of you don't understand this problem.

Comment: It's not that (c) is meaningless, it's just... unusual. So if it's intentional, ok: You *can* compute what a valuation assigns to it. The outer quantifier *does nothing* it just goes away. Only the inner one $\exists x_1$ matters. $x_2$ is then a free variable, and gets whatever value $v$ assigns to that variable. The formula is then true iff there's some integer that's < the value assigned to $x_2$ by the valuation. ... Similarly, if (d) is intentional, then the quantifiers just don't matter, and the value is the truth value of $v(x_1) < v(x_2)$.

Comment: We would like confirmation that they're intentional - they're eyebrow-raising formulas. As in my previous comment, they're uncommon but not ill-formed, and they have a value under any valuation. It's syntactically ok to quantify a variable that's already bound, or which doesn't even occur, in a formula. So perhaps that's the point of the exercise: "vacuous quantifiers" don't matter. Anyway, in (c), your valuation needs to assign a value to $x_2$